# jQuery animate step transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, transform

I am facing problem with jQuery animate now property. 
But it's always increment current value. 
i want it will start from 0 and will end at 20 every time in loop. Here is my code

```js
var container = $('#top_slides');

    var items = container.children('.top_slide_sp');
    
    var lengths = items.length;
    var index = 0;
    var transition_speed = 5000;
    var transSP = function(){
        items.eq(index).animate({
            'opacity': '100',
             now: '+=20'
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0, 0)");
            },
            duration: 6000,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }, 'linear');
    };
    
    var show = function(){
        items.eq(index).fadeOut(800, function(){
            index += 1;
            if (index === lengths) {
                index = 0;
            }
               transSP();

            items.eq(index).fadeIn(800, function(){
                items.removeClass('active');
                items.eq(index).addClass('active');
                
                setTimeout(show, transition_speed);
            });
        });
    };
    
    // Show first item
    items.eq(index).addClass('active').fadeIn(400, function () {
      
           transSP();
        
        setTimeout(show, transition_speed);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_slides">

<div class="top_slide_sp">1</div>
<div class="top_slide_sp">2</div>
<div class="top_slide_sp">3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code the plus(+) was the problem

```
{
            'opacity': '100',
             now: '+=20' <--------
}
```

Remove and lets try like this

```
{
            'opacity': '100',
             now: '=20'
        }
```

Comment: Tx. I tried with like your code. but u can see it's incremented untill 100px not 20px

Comment: make a 20px div over all the  .top_slide_sp class divs  and make it 100% instead of 100px

Comment: I solved by my way. tx for ur time and suggestion. i used default now and made it 20 by deviding it.   $(this).css('transform', "translate3d(" + (now/2-30) + "px, 0, 0)");

Comment: var transSP = function(){
        items.eq(index).animate({
            'opacity': '100',
             now: '=20'
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                var upto20 = (now / 100) * 20
                $(this).css('transform', "translate3d(" + upto20 + "px, 0, 0)");
            },
            duration: 6000,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }, 'linear');
    };